# Webpack error after upgrading to .NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack

So the error I get in the browser is:

> bootstrap 050c815…:578Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app/main.ts"

and when I try run `webpack` from cmd I get

> ERROR in ./app/main.ts
>   Module build failed: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
>      at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
>      at Object.dirname (path.js:697:5)
>      at ensureTypeScriptInstance (C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\TemplateProjects\CoreAngular2WebpackSass\src\CoreAngular2WebpackSass\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:156:103)
>      at Object.loader (C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\TemplateProjects\CoreAngular2WebpackSass\src\CoreAngular2WebpackSass\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:403:14)

I've commented out almost everything that's needed from the app but still getting this error.

Im not sure how else to debug this issue, it was working when I was on .NET Core RC 2 but the error dosent look like a .net related issue, which makes me think it might have messed something up when copying code over but I cannot see

Here's my`webpack.config` located in the root

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('extendify')({ isDeep: true, arrays: 'concat' });
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');
var devConfig = require('./webpack.config.dev');
var prodConfig = require('./webpack.config.prod');
var isDevelopment = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT === 'Development';

//if (isDevelopment) {
    module.exports = merge({
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            main: ['./app/main.ts']
        },
        output: {
            path: 'wwwroot/dist/',//path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ]
    },  devConfig );
//}
```

`main.ts` located at `app/main.ts`

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
//import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER } from './app.routes';
//import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
//import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    //APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER,
    //HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    //disableDeprecatedForms(),
    //provideForms()
]);

//Hot swapping
//declare var module: any;
//if (module.hot) {
//    module.hot.accept();
//}
```

And my `app.component.ts` located at `app/app.component.ts`

```
import { Component}       from '@angular/core';
//import { AppFooter}         from './shared/footer/footer.component'
//import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
//import { AccountService } from './services/account/account.service'
//import './rxjs-operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: 'hi',//require('./app.html'),
    //directives: [AppFooter, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
   // providers: [AccountService]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And finally the index which serve it all up: located at `Views/home/Index.cshtml` which is the default page to be served up by the app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <base href="." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <app asp-prerender-webpack-config="webpack.config.js">Loading...</app>   
    @*<script src="webpack.config.js" asp-append-version="true"> </script> *@   
    <script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>    
    <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and I found the solution here: [Fixing webpack error: Path must be a string. Received undefined](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/fixing-webpack-error-path-must-string-received-undefined)

The solution is to create tsconfig.json. Something like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
      "./typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```